# Escape Spaces in QT

Tags: qt, path, escaping, filepath

I want to use the QString.split(' ') method to split a input command into the command

```
    QStringList commandList =  command.split(' ');
```

however command has a UNIX path at the end of it. i.e. it looks something like

```
    QString command = new QString("caommand -a -b /path/to\ specific/file");
```

the path command is specified by the user at runtime(the user escapes any spaces in the path). For some reason command.split(' '); does not escape the spaces.

I am new to QT, how does it escape spaces?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QDir::toNativeSeparators()` to convert it to unix style. And split received result by spaces, though you have got to figure out where are the spaces between commands and where are the possible spaces in filename

For example:

```
QString myUnixPath = QDir::toNativeSeparators("/home/path with spaces/");
```

will return unix style path, while

```
QString qtPath = QDir::fromNativeSeparators("/path/with\ spaces/");
```

will return /path with spaces/