# Qt5 escape spaces in path

Tags: c++, qt, escaping, qt5, space

I have found few [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512207/escape-spaces-in-qt) but they don't work on my Qt5.3.1 build.

I have a `QProcess` which I need to run with a file path as argument:

> /home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/user/Local Settings/LocalLow/A B
>   C/test/test1

When I try to run the program through this `QProcess` object it fails because it does not have escaped spaces. Then I tried to fix it by using `QDir::toNativeSeparators` but it does not work:

```
QDir::toNativeSeparators("/home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/user/Local Settings/LocalLow/A B C/test/test1")
```

returns exactly the same string as I pass as argument.

That is how I start the process:

```
QProcess process;
QStringList arguments;
arguments.append(binaryDir);
process.setArguments(arguments);
process.setProgram("wine");
process.start();
```

P.S. I can't fix it manually because the path is coming somewhere from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways. You can either use escaped quotes (inserting the string between quotes) :

```
QStringList arguments;
QString str="\"/home/user/.wine/drive_c/users/user/Local Settings/LocalLow/A B C/test/test1\"";
arguments.append(str);
```

Or use the `QStringList()` overload of `start`  which does the escaping automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the arguments to QProcess as a QStringList, this will not take spaces into account.

Here's a small snippet to test with your favorite file manager.

```
static QString arg="/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/";
static QProcess p;
p.start("/usr/bin/dolphin", QStringList(arg));
```

Comment: Spaces are taken into account for me.